# Trying to access IIS application outside server

Tags: python, flask, iis, server

Trying to access the IIS-based Flask Application outside the server but returning "This site can’t be reached10.154.0.2 took too long to respond." I have an inbound rule from an advanced firewall and my port is 88, it's working fine inside the server but outside it returns this.

[image]

Comment: What's your site bindings? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: This is a Python Flask App, Not ASP .net application

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your Inbound Rules, it seems you have failed to set inbound rules previous. You can show us the screenshot, let us help you check.

You can follow below steps and test again. And you also need to delete the previous one.

[image]

## Test Steps

1. I tried delete the inbound rules in my vm and I can reproduce the issue
2. For you, please allow a new port like: 80 or 8000, and edit the `Site Bindings` to 80 or 8000 port.

Comment: Hi, i have already added inbound rule 88, and i also bind new port 9090, both ports are added in new in-bound rules but still result is the same.

Comment: here is the rule. https://pasteboard.co/N8of2HpqNXg0.png

Comment: Here is the binding, https://pasteboard.co/cvXrkWRDAYog.png

Comment: @kashifaws How many network cards does your server have?